# 'Pupil' object is not iterable

Tags: python, class, object

I have this code here where I want to get the average of the numbers of these 2 individuals, but I get the error " 'Pupil' object is not iterable", where is the error in the code?

```
def average(self, a):
    return sum(self) / 3 == sum(a) / 3

class Pupil:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

# Numbers
data = []
data.append(["Jim", 2.0, 5.0, 7.0])
data.append(["Sam", 2.0, 6.0, 4.0])

############################
A = []
for i in data:
    tmp = Pupil(i)
    A.append(tmp)
print(average(A[0], A[1]))
```

Comment: What do you want to calculate the average of? Of Jim's data and Sam's? Or the average of all Jim's numbers?

Comment: Fix your indentation. The `average` function needs to be inside a class definition.

Comment: It should be `sum(self.data[1:]) / (len(self.data)-1)`

Comment: It would be better if the name were a separate argument, not mixed into the data array.

Comment: @ErikXIII I want see if the average between Sam's and Jim's numbers are the same, sorry for not mentioning, I forgot, also @Barmar I fixed the indentation but no the `print` tells me that the name `average` is not defined

Comment: Gave you an answer with that solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want to do something like this:
Add name to class pupil and then extract data when you calculate sum.

```
def average(a, b):
    return sum(a.data) / 3 == sum(b.data) / 3

class Pupil:
    def __init__(self, name, data):
        self.name = name
        self.data = data
    
# Numbers
data = []
data.append(["Jim", 2.0, 5.0, 7.0])
data.append(["Sam", 2.0, 6.0, 4.0])

############################
A = []
for i in data:
    tmp = Pupil(i[0], i[1:])
    A.append(tmp)

print(average(A[0], A[1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stackoverflow!

Generally in a situation like this, we can keep our results more organized in a dictionary - let's take a look.

```
# -------------------------------- STATIC VARIABLES ----------------------------------------
data     = {}                   # Hold all of our data in a DICTIONARY
averages = {}                   # This is where our ANSWER will be

# -------------------------------- DATA TO WORK WITH ---------------------------------------

data["Jim"] = [2.0, 5.0, 7.0]   # ADD JIM with LIST
data["Sam"] = [2.0, 6.0, 4.0]   # ADD SAM with LIST

print(f'{data} \n')             # Let's make sure everything is here

for keys in data:
    print(f"{keys}'s results are --> {data[keys]} with an average of {float(sum(data[keys]) / len(data[keys]))}")
    averages[keys] = float(sum(data[keys]) / len(data[keys]))

print(f'\n {averages}')
```

With this code, we get an output that looks like this...

```
{'Jim': [2.0, 5.0, 7.0], 'Sam': [2.0, 6.0, 4.0]} 

Jim's results are --> [2.0, 5.0, 7.0] with an average of 4.666666666666667
Sam's results are --> [2.0, 6.0, 4.0] with an average of 4.0

 {'Jim': 4.666666666666667, 'Sam': 4.0}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Notice how we aren't tied down to thinking that results can only be 3 separate readings, by using the equations sum(data[keys]) / len(data[keys]) it isolates EVERYTHING that we need in a quick and swift action. If you wanted to perhaps keep things even easier with the lists - you could iterate them even further so the program adds them to our data dictionary automatically.